# How can Flutter handle dpi text and image size differences

Tags: flutter

We are currently in the process of evaluating whether Flutter is a good platform to build a new app on. So we wanted to make sure that our app looks good on devices with different DPIs. Given that we are supporting both iOS and Android, and the folder structure of iOS and Android to support the different image sizes vary, is there a solution available on Flutter to achieve this?

The same question applies to text sizes where we hope to change our text sizes depending on dpi.

Answer (score 29):

Flutter supports loading of assets by automatically choosing DPI dependent resources, see https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#declaring-resolution-aware-image-assets for how the mechanism works.

Flutter should scale text according to devicePixelRatio value. Here is an example app showing you how that works:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  MediaQueryData queryData;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    double devicePixelRatio = queryData.devicePixelRatio;
    TextStyle style38 = new TextStyle(
      inherit: true,
      fontSize: 38.0,
    );
    TextStyle style20 = new TextStyle(
      inherit: true,
      fontSize: 20.0,
    );
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          new Text(
            'Button tapped $_counter time${ _counter == 1 ? '' : 's' }.',
            style: style38,
          ),
          new Text(
            'size (pixels): w=${queryData.size.width * devicePixelRatio}, h=${queryData.size.height * devicePixelRatio}',
            style: style20,
          ),
          new Text(
            'devicePixelRatio: $devicePixelRatio',
            style: style20,
          ),
          new Text(
            'size: w=${queryData.size.width}, h=${queryData.size.height}',
            style: style20,
          ),
          new Text(
            'textScaleFactor: w=${queryData.textScaleFactor}',
            style: style20,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's a modified version of the default Flutter app showing the device viewport size in pixels, the devicePixelRatio value, the size in absolute pixels. See the screenshot of the app running on Android in 3 different resolutions, and then iOS emulator with iPhone 7 Plus screen resolution. The screen resolutions are:

1. Android 1440 x 2560, devicePixelRatio: 3.5
2. Android 1080 x 1920, devicePixelRatio: 2.625
3. Android 720 x 1280, devicePixelRatio: 1.75
4. iOS emulator 1080 x 1920 (iPhone 7 Plus), devicePixelRatio: 3.0

The text on all devices is scaled according to the actual screen size and logical viewport.

[image]

Comment: actually in my App fonsize isn't scaled correctly it looks way too big on smal resolution devices

Comment: @Thomas, have you found something else to fix your issues?

Comment: @raju-bitter, like Thomas, the font size behave the same. I was expecting to see smaller font size with my iphone 5S comparing to my Pixel 2. Is it possible there is somthing missing in your example code? Which simulator did you use and which phones? Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I am using a Pixel 2XL and an iPhone 5se.
The text size remains exactly the same on both devices which causes a view overflow on the iPhone with the small screen.

Comment: Actually, flutter *did* scale the font size, but not as what we have thought. Flutter renders exact physical size of the texts across all screen size. We might have wanted the texts to be smaller on smaller phones (usually for aesthetic purposes), but we can't expect users with smaller phones can see smaller texts. The physical size still matters. If you're still expecting to see smaller texts on smaller phones, you'll have to scale them yourself using MediaQuery

Comment: Take the device scale factor and multiple with height and width pixel you will get dpi and it's looks same in all devices

Answer (score 10):

For smaller devices, I created an optional scaler.

We test on many different devices including the iPhone SE 4" and Android devices with extremely high DPI as default. Works well.

```
double scaleSmallDevice(BuildContext context) {
  final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  // For tiny devices.
  if (size.height < 600) {
    return 0.7;
  }
  // For normal devices.
  return 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some useful math utils for responsive scaling:

```dart
final window = WidgetsBinding.instance.window;
Size size = window.physicalSize / window.devicePixelRatio;

/// This method is used to set padding/margin (for the left and Right side)
/// and width of the screen or widget according to the Viewport width.
double getHorizontalSize(double px) => px * (size.width / 375);

/// This method is used to set padding/margin (for the top and bottom side)
/// and height of the screen or widget according to the Viewport height.
double getVerticalSize(double px) {
  num statusBar = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).viewPadding.top;
  num screenHeight = size.height - statusBar;
  return px * (screenHeight / 812);
}

/// This method is used to set smallest px in image height and width.
double getSize(double px) {
  final height = getVerticalSize(px);
  final width = getHorizontalSize(px);

  if (height < width) {
    return height.toInt().toDouble();
  } else {
    return width.toInt().toDouble();
  }
}

/// This method is used to set text font size according to Viewport.
double getFontSize(double px) => getSize(px);
```