# How to use MediaQuery to set scaleFactor for text in Flutter?

Tags: text, dart, flutter, scale

With MediaQuery I can get height and width of my Samsung S7 Edge screen size so I can work with it. But how to use MediaQuery to layout the multiple column dynamic text in ListTile? In my demo project I set the text size to 12 and in Samsung S6 I get overflow issues... Any info or example for text scale factor in Flutter?

I found one solution here ([How can Flutter handle dpi text and image size differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173641/how-can-flutter-handle-dpi-text-and-image-size-differences/51786199#51786199)) and I try to build demo project. S6 textScaleFactor is 1.1 an the S7 is 1.0....

My original demo app that I test it with S7 text size was 12. And when I try to test it in S6 I get overflow issue... I need to scale down or up with MediaQuery  to set  text scale factor, so it can work most of the devices without getting a overflow issues?

In ListTile I have a column that has 4 separate lines of text and all the value comes from database. If the text value is long I get a overflow issues on S6 device. So my question is How to use MediaQuery to set scaleFactor for text in Flutter?

**Update:**

```
new ListTile(
    trailing: new Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
    onTap: () {

    },
    title: new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(
          ‘My Account Details:’,
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
        ),
      ],
    ),
    subtitle: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(‘Hello Flutter’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),

            new Text(’Today is **************’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(‘Name’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
            new Text(‘Dart’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(’Surname’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
            new Text(‘Flutter’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(‘Account Name: Let’s Flutter all day long till down with fancy User Interface’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
            new Text(‘109.65’,
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: put your code here please

Comment: @diegoveloper I add my code...

Comment: Just a note: it's unadvised to change that "global" setting, because it'll affect ADA features, like changes screen display aid or screen reader as well. So you'd rather just want to change widget or text style sizes. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcaxkIg5Fk0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve your issue wrapping your `Text` widget into a `Flexible` to avoid the overflow. I put maxLines 1 to see the Fade overflow :

```
          new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Text(
                        "Account Name: Let's Flutter all day long till down with fancy User Interface",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: myTextSize, color: Colors.black54),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      "109.65",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

I added a global variable :

```
  var myTextSize = 12.0;
```

Also you can use the `LayoutBuilder` in order to get the `maxHeight` or `maxWidth` of your device, after that you can change the text size like this example:

```
  var myTextSize = 12.0;

  return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, boxConstraints) {
        print(boxConstraints.maxHeight);
        if (boxConstraints.maxHeight <= 667.0){
            myTextSize = 10.0;
        }
        return Container(
          child: new ListTile(
            trailing: new Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
            onTap: () {},
            title: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  "My Account Details:",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      "Hello Flutter",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize, color: Colors.black54),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      "Today is **************",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize, color: Colors.black54),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      "Name",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize, color: Colors.black54),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      "Dart",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize, color: Colors.black54),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      "Surname",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize, color: Colors.black54),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      "Flutter",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: new Text(
                        "Account Name: Let's Flutter all day long till down with fancy User Interface",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: myTextSize, color: Colors.black54),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      "109.65",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: myTextSize,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
```

Comment: where did you get .maxHeight <= 667.0 ? I am going to try it now

Comment: If you use LayoutBuilder, you cant get the constraints and make your validation, I was using a random number, you have to use your own value based on your device

Comment: looks like is working... My emulator Nexus 4 maxHeight is 302.8 so all the text fontsize become 10.  So, how do I use in all devices?

Comment: You can define some ranges 300 , 400, 600 and change according that. https://material.io/tools/devices/

Answer (score 4):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WidgetsApp(
    // ...
    builder: (context, child) {
      final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);

      return MediaQuery(
        data: mediaQueryData.copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.5),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the Text font size to be Responsive
this is a simple trick

```
fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05 //u can play with equation
```

or

```
 fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 500  ?60 
           : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 300 ?40: 30,
```