# How do I use Text Scale Factor property in flutter

Tags: css, flutter, text, mobile

I am having problems with my app.. When i set the fontSize on my phone it works OK but on other peoples phones due to there phone fontSize settings it is affecting the size of the text in my app.. I heard text scale factor can help but i do not know how to use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use MediaQuery to set scaleFactor for text in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786364/how-to-use-mediaquery-to-set-scalefactor-for-text-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks but I had seen this earlier and do not understand how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor` but I think using [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text#-readme-tab-) is more efficient.

**EDIT** **2** :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Text(
      'Hello, How are you?',
      textScaleFactor : MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize : 18),
    );
}
```

And you can check the usage of this property from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/textScaleFactor.html) as well as TextStyle class from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html).

Comment: Please can you show me this your suggestion in an actual code.. Do i put it in the style or where

Comment: Oh thanks bro. Just one thing. Now that am using textScaleFactor do i need to define font Size in the style.. cause textScaleFactor makes a font Size constant so now what font Size is it using as the constant..

Comment: I think you need to specify the font size because textScaleFactor is just a factor that is multiplied by the initial font size you already specified. From text widget API reference : 'For example, if the text scale factor is 1.5, text will be 50% larger than the specified font size'

Comment: Thanks bro I will try that out... just on more thing can you just show me a full example in code form where you use text scale factor and fontSize.. And do i always have type the textScaleFactor in all the Text widget to get them to work

Comment: I've edited my answer, and yes you have to define textScaleFactor in 'style' property of Text widget.

Comment: The `textScaleFactor` property is deprecated.